# Generate number with fixed size in java

Tags: android

I would like to generate a number between 0 and 9999 for an android application , that I would increment each time.
The generated string must be fixed size.
For example, for 0, I would like to have '0000'
             for 1, I would like to have '0001'
             etc.

Any ideas would be welcome.
thanks

Comment: Use String formatted = String.format("%03d", num);

Answer (score 1):

Using StringUtils leftpad

```
// StringUtils.leftPad("your number", "length", 'padding character');
StringUtils.leftPad("0", 4, '0');
```

The lib http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonlang3jar.htm or https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Comment: It would have been nice to include in the answer the fact that it requires an external library... Like in the answers in the linked question.